# How to get all json levels from different entities in one rest method?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest

Java.String-boot.Rest api. There are three entities: media, question, answer. media and question are connected many-to-many. Question and answer are related one-to- many. Accordingly, media "does not see" the answers, that  "sees" only question.

```
public class Media {
...

      @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
      @JoinTable(name = "media_question", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "media_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
          @JoinColumn(name = "question_id") })
      private Set<Question> questions = new HashSet<>();
    ...
    }   
    
public class Question {
...
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
      cascade = {
          CascadeType.PERSIST,
          CascadeType.MERGE
      },
      mappedBy = "questions")


  @JsonIgnore
  private Set<Media> medias = new HashSet<>();
...
}

public class Answer {
...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id", nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Question question;
...
}
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/medias/{id}")
  public ResponseEntity<Media> getMediaById(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    Media media= mediaRepository.findById(id)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Not found Media with id = " + id));

    return new ResponseEntity<>(media, HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

JSON must be with answers, but it doesn't :

```
 [![{
              "id": 5,
              "title": "test",
              "description": "so so",
              "published": true,
              "questions": [
                {
                  "id": 9,
                  "name": "How many?"
                  "answers":[
                    {
                      "id": 1,
                      "name": "5"
                    },
                    {
                      "id": 2,
                      "name": "2"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }]
```

Comment: Do not use entity classes at controller level. Learn about 3tier architecture.

Comment: Yes. I know, this code without service, i use Repository, Entity, Controller only. But how to add nested class to question in json?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add @OneToMany mapping between Question and Answers